# Why Disabling Interrupts Synchronization Satisfies Bounded Waiting

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, starvation

**Definition**: Bounded waiting refers to a process `P_i` that keeps waiting forever to enter critical section (CS) while other processes `P_j` keep entering CS although `P_i` has shown interest to enter CS.

Now, I understand why **lock variable mechanism** is not bounded waiting because if a process entered a non-critical section, then another process might come and take CS, so a process might starve.

**Algorithm**:

```
NCS (Non-critical Section)
DISABLE INTERRUPTS
CS
ENABLE INTERRUPTS
NCS
```

**Edit**: no more details are given about schedulers, etc. The question is to get a glance whether this satisfies bounded waiting or not.

**Question**: can you please explain why disabled interrupts synchronization mechanism satisfies bounded waiting please (a process can not starve to enter CS as in lock variable mechanism)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has two contexts to consider:

1. Are interrupt handlers entering the Critical Section?
2. Is there an asynchronous scheduler involved?

**No,No**
As soon as `P_i` releases the CS, the release mechanism can accept `P_j`, thus starvation is averted.

**No,Yes**
Despite `P_j`'s desire, once interrupts are released, the scheduler could be invoked, and decide that `P_j` is not to be executed next, so in at least a pathological case, could spend forever trying to enter the CS while others are selected.

**Yes,No**
As soon as `P_i` release the interrupt, any pending interrupts will execute immediately.  If they are to enter the CS, they will first (otherwise the system has halted [*]), so with the right timing a set of interrupts could keep `P_j` starved forever.

**Yes,Yes**
Here, the starvation could happen for either of the reasons No,Yes or Yes,No.

[*] - Interrupts have no a-priori way of deferring work, so any resources required to complete the interrupt handler must be available when the handler runs.  The handlers context is effectively nested; and a nested context cannot wait for the completion of its superior context.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added details please and have edited the question. Can you please double check?

Comment: What do you mean please by ,'Are interrupt handlers entering the Critical Section?'?

Comment: Interrupt handlers are functions called in response to an interrupt by some kernel mechanism.   They typically execute within the context of the current process.  If such a function attempts to enter the critical section, it causes problems with the determinism as pointed out above.

Comment: **No,Yes** `Despite P_j's desire, once interrupts are released, the scheduler could be invoked, and decide that P_j is not to be executed next,` Please can you help me out in the following: When P_j shows its desire to enter CS, it does so, by entering the "Entry Section", right? If so, then it shall disable the interrupt.. and there is now no chance that P_j shall be preempted... So P_j shall be the only one to enter CS... And there is bounded waiting for sure...

Comment: Once it has disabled interrupts, it is safe from the scheduler.   The problem here is that it could be preempted on the instruction before disabling interrupts, and never be selected for execution again.  If that is not possible, then your scheduler has solved the problem.